# Change the way the text is display on screen with html and css

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am setting up a simple blog website and need help formatting the posts that are submitted to the front page of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in multiple ways. Maybe the easiest way is to put your text in a container and give this a width. The text will wrap itself.

```
<div class="text">Your text here</div>
```

and your CSS. If you want to break within the word you can use `word-wrap:break-word;`.

```
.text {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options for this. simple one put you text in a `<div>` tag and give width to `div` as much you like.

```
<div style="width:100px">"Hello, this is my first post. As you can see, it wraps all the way around the text box and into another line."</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a word-wrap css property and set it to break-word. This forces the text to wrap inside a container.

```
.container {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```